# Call a function in an ExtJS XTemplate

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm familiar with using a function to determine a specific condition using xtemplate but not sure how to directly call a function without the conditional if statement.

My code, for example, wants to append some characters to a string that I am using within my xtemplate.  I think the best way to do it is append the characters when the xtemplate is rendered.

```
var myTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
  '<tpl for=".">',

    '<tpl if="this.isThumbnailed(thumbnailed) == true">',

      '<img src=this.getThumbUrl(rawThumbUrl)/>', //this call to function does not work, also tried variations of this.

    '</tpl>',

  '</tpl>',

 {
  isThumbnailed : function(thumbnailed) {
    return ...;
  },
  getThumbUrl : function(rawThumbUrl) {
    //... //this function does not get called.
    return ...;
  }

 }
)
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Have a look at the [XTemplate constructor](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.XTemplate.html) API docs.  There are lots of good examples there.  Quoting:

> Anything between {[ ... ]} is considered code to be executed in the scope of the template.

So you should be able to do something like:

```
'<img src={[this.getThumbUrl(rawThumbUrl)]} />',
```

Comment: Found that, If function is global then 

'<img src=getThumbUrl(rawThumbUrl)/>' will do the trick

Comment: i am trying this same method but its not working in IE 11. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 30):

To call functions defined in the scope, you need to use the syntax:

```
{[this.functionName(values.valueName)]}
```

In your case, you can call:

```
'<img src="{[this.getThumbUrl(values.rawThumbUrl)]}"/>',
```

If you want to use a function defined outside of the template context, then remove `this.` from the function call.

Comment: Thanks, Notice that "values" is the variable which has the attribute of template current record. For example, values.birthDate etc.

Answer (score 14):

Was trying to figure this out myself the other day and came across a solution for getting click events working. The short answer is you need to make use of the .defer function to setup event listeners after the template has been rendered.

Here's the example I found:

```
var resultTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="search-item">',
            '<a id={[this.getLinkId()]} href="violation.aspx?violationid={slvha}">',
                '<img src="images/icons/home.gif" style="float:left;padding-right:2px">{number}&nbsp;{street}',
            '</a>',
            '<p>Owners:&nbsp;{owners}',
            '<br/>Flag Code:&nbsp;{flag}',
            '<br/>Number of Violations:&nbsp;[{summary}]</p>',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>', {
    getLinkId: function(values) {
        var result = Ext.id();
        this.addListener.defer(1, this, [result]);
        return result;
    },
    addListener: function(id) {
        Ext.get(id).on('click', function(e){e.stopEvent(); alert('link ' + id + ' clicked');})
    }
});
```

[Source](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?37614-SOLVED-Add-event-to-an-element-within-an-Ext.XTemplate&p=177888#post177888)

Comment: For version 5 and onwards, addListener can be written as : Ext.Function.defer(this.addListener, 1, this,[result]);

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Reference the value directly e.g. `{myValue}`
- Pass it to a function e.g. `{[this.myFunction(values.myValue)]}`.

Below is an example that works with all versions of ExtJS.

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    subdata: { x: 10, y: 20 }
}, {
    id: 2,
    subdata: { x: 20, y: 30 }
}];

var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate([
    '<ul>',
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<li>ID: <span class="raw">{id}</span> or ',
            '<span class="fmt">{["#" + this.pad(values.id, 3, "0")]}</span></li>',
        '<ul>',
        '<tpl for="subdata">',
            '<li>x: <span class="raw">{x}</span> or ',
                '<span class="fmt">{[this.frmtUnits(values.x)]}</span></li>',
            '<li>y: <span class="raw">{y}</span> or ',
                '<span class="fmt">{[this.frmtUnits(values.y)]}</span></li>',
        '</tpl>',
        '</ul>',
    '</tpl>',
    '</ul>',
    {
     pad : function(s, n, c) {
            if (typeof s !== 'string') s = '' + s;
            return Math.abs(n) <= s.length ? s : this.pad(n > 0 ? c + s : s + c, n, c);
        },
        frmtUnits : function(v) {
            return v + 'px';
        }
    }
]);

Ext.onReady(function () {
    new Ext.Panel({
        autoHeight: true,
        html: tpl.apply(data),
        layout: 'fit',
        style: { padding: '2px', margin: '2px' },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

```css
ul li {
    line-height: 1.67em;
}
li span {
    font-weight: bold;
}
li span.raw {
    color: #D44;
}
li span.fmt {
    color: #44D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```