# ExtJS - How to use a variable within a list itemTpl that isn't bound to the store

Tags: extjs

How do you get a list's `itemTpl` to interpret variables that are not a part of its immediate store / data binding? For example, I want to refer to some viewModel data of a parent component. Here's the simplest example I could come up with:

```
Ext.define('ListItemTplTest.view.main.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'mainview',

    viewModel : {
        data : {
            message: 'is available'
        }
    },

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '{title} {message}', // how to get the itemTpl to interpret the message variable?
            data: [
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 4' }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

Assume that the viewModel's `message` property can be updated to different values (ex/ press a button, and a controller will update the message), so hardcoding `'is available'` into the `itemTpl` won't work.

Although my real use case is a bit different (child and parent store instead of child and parent data), the underlying principle is the same: My list component needs to interpret variables from a parent data source.

This applies to ExtJS 7.3.1 using modern toolkit.

Comment: You can write js function for the same also right. Inside that function you can access any thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611820/call-a-function-in-an-extjs-xtemplate

Comment: When I add such a function and place a debugger, what I have access to is pretty limited. Beyond the xtemplate supported variables `out, values, parent, xindex, xcount, xkey`, there's hardly any data on `this`. For example, this.getViewModel(), this.lookup(), etc don't work. So how do I access my parent view model from there?

Comment: I am not saying to access anything thr args, but I am saying that you can access other things like any component or other store by Ext.getStore().

Answer (score 0):

- https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.dataview.List.html#cfg-viewModel

According to the docs, you can bind the data property for example.

Here is a fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dvl

```
  let list = Ext.create({
        xtype: 'list',
        viewModel: {
            data: {
                tplData: [{
                    title: 'Item 1',
                    message: 'a'
                }, {
                    title: 'Item 2',
                    message: 'b'
                }, {
                    title: 'Item 3',
                    message: 'c'
                }, {
                    title: 'Item 4',
                    message: 'd'
                }]
            }
        },
        fullscreen: true,
        itemTpl: '{title} {message}',
        bind: {
            data: '{tplData}'
        }
    });
    
    Ext.defer(function() {
        list.getViewModel().set('tplData', [{
            title: 'Item 4',
            message: 'a'
        }])
        list.getViewModel().notify() // not sure if really needed
    }.bind(list), 2000)
```